# MSSql to MySQL conversion creates CS errors

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

While trying to covert Mssql code to MySQL, specifically during a MysqlCommand request I have created  CS1026, CS1002 and a CS1513 error codes,
here is the Mssql code:

```
 try
        {
            sqlConnect = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=" + SQLServerAddress + "," + SQLServerPort + "; initial catalog=" + DatabaseName + "; Integrated Security=SSPI");
            sqlConnect.Open();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd = new    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT ImageFileName, FacePositionXc,   FacePositionYc, FacePositionW, FacePositionAngle, Eye1X, Eye1Y, Eye2X, Eye2Y, Template, Image, FaceImage FROM FaceList", sqlConnect);

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
```

I tried to translate this to MySQL as:

```
            string conn = "server=localhost; uid=user;" +
            "pwd=password; database=database;";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connection.Open(); 
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

            cmd.Connection = connection;

            cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT ImageFileName, FacePositionXc, FacePositionYc, FacePositionW, FacePositionAngle, Eye1X, Eye1Y, Eye2X, Eye2Y, Template, Image, FaceImage FROM faces", connection);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
  {
                TFaceRecord fr = new TFaceRecord();
                fr.ImageFileName = reader.GetString(4);

                fr.FacePosition = new FSDK.TFacePosition();
                fr.FacePosition.xc = reader.GetInt32(5);
                fr.FacePosition.yc = reader.GetInt32(6);
                fr.FacePosition.w = reader.GetInt32(7);
                fr.FacePosition.angle = reader.GetFloat(8);

                fr.FacialFeatures = new FSDK.TPoint[2];
                fr.FacialFeatures[0] = new FSDK.TPoint();
                fr.FacialFeatures[0].x = reader.GetInt32(9);
                fr.FacialFeatures[0].y = reader.GetInt32(10);
                fr.FacialFeatures[1] = new FSDK.TPoint();
                fr.FacialFeatures[1].x = reader.GetInt32(11);
                fr.FacialFeatures[1].y = reader.GetInt32(12);

                fr.Template = new byte[FSDK.TemplateSize];
                reader.GetBytes(9, 0, fr.Template, 0, FSDK.TemplateSize);

                Image img = Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(reader.GetInt32(14)));
                Image img_face = Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(reader.GetInt32(15)));
                fr.image = new FSDK.CImage(img);
                fr.faceImage = new FSDK.CImage(img_face);


                FaceList.Add(fr);

                imageList1.Images.Add(fr.faceImage.ToCLRImage());
                string fn = fr.ImageFileName;
                listView1.Items.Add((imageList1.Images.Count - 1).ToString(), fn.Split('\\')[fn.Split('\\').Length - 1], imageList1.Images.Count - 1);

                textBox1.Text += "File '" + fn + "' read from database\r\n";

                img.Dispose();
                img_face.Dispose();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception on loading database");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
                // LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is generated at the end of the command text ' **", connection )** '

Removing the ', connection'  creates a 'Unable to cast object of type ‘symbol.Byte[] to type ‘System.Convertable’' on the error exception.

Could anyone please advise on the correct syntax to use or where my mistake is thank you.

Comment: Sharing the text of the exceptions would be useful.

Comment: `CommandText` is a property, not a method, you cant pass it a string and an object as you currently are.

Comment: To assign the connection use `cmd.Connection = connection;`

Comment: @Alex K have edited as you suggested but errors still show.

Comment: @Alex K I did 'Unable to cast object of type ‘symbol.Byte[] to type ‘System.Convertable'